# Can I put comments in mpd playlist?

Tags: comments, playlist, mpd

The title says it all...

Running Ubuntu 12.04 and the mpd daemon.

I am writing some scripts to manipulate the playlists (for my wife and me,) and it would be handy to have comments in the playlist rather then create a separate log file.

So, canI, canI, canI???

Straight from my 5 year old.

Comment: Out of curiosity, what sort of comments do you want? Extended description per playlist? Per-song, per-playlist information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot. Here is the full list of [all MPD commands related to stored playlists](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/protocol/playlist_files.html):

- listplaylist {NAME}
- listplaylistinfo {NAME}
- listplaylists
- load {NAME} [START:END]
- playlistadd {NAME} {URI}
- playlistclear {NAME}
- playlistdelete {NAME} {SONGPOS}
- playlistmove {NAME} {FROM} {TO}
- rename {NAME} {NEW_NAME}
- rm {NAME}
- save {NAME}

You can use ["stickers"](https://www.musicpd.org/doc/protocol/stickers.html) to associate arbitrary information per song, but sadly (and inexplicably) you cannot (yet?) associate stickers with playlists.

You can also read all comments from a song file using `readcomments`.